# Create object automatically after saving another object

Tags: python, django

I have a car heading towards a series of possible, predefined locations.

```
class locations(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
coordinates = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

In this example, the objects created are New York, Ohio, and Wyoming. Then I have a type of car with the following attributes:

```
class cars(models.Model):
type = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
MaxRange = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=Decimal('0.000'))
Speed = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=Decimal('0.000'))

def __str__(self):
    return self.type
```

When the car departs, that is tracked by another table with values pertaining to when the car could arrive at locations given by the model, locations.

```
class departure(models.Model):
car_name = models.ForeignKey(cars, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
location_name =  models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
range_or_not = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
arrival_time = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    for loc in location.objects.all():
        self.location_name = #calculation
        self.range_or_not = #calculation
        self.arrival_time = #calculation

        super(departure, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.location_name
```

When the user selects a group and creates a departure, I want to loop through all the locations and generate calculated values pertaining to each of those locations such as: the possible arrival time of a car for all locations inputed in the locations model. I'm not sure how to automatically create a new departure object for every location object. Right now, I am only able to return values for one location per departure.

In the end, the output for one departure would be:

car_name| group_name| range_or_not| arrival_time

New York| Group A   | In Range    |12:30|

Ohio    | Group A   | Not in Range| 14:45|

Wyoming | Group A   | Not in Range| 18:45|

Thank you for any input.

******This is an example of what I want to do, not my actual models.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is better to use [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/)